# upgrade Sagepay v2.23 to v3.00 Form - php5.1.6 installed - will it work?

Tags: php, forms, upgrade, opayo

Ok, I've delayed and delayed the Sagepay Form upgrade from v2.23 to v3.00 but now it is crunch time.

I think the reason for initially delaying is because my websites are hosted on PHP 5.1.6 and was unsure if this would work.

Can I upgrade to version 3.00 on this php version?

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine as long as you can install (or have installed) the mcrypt extension (for AES encryption of the crypt string). See [Sagepay 2.22 to 3.00 form upgrade - PHP update to AES encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842023/sagepay-2-22-to-3-00-form-upgrade-php-update-to-aes-encryption) for some extra help....

Comment: Thanks Rik, I will take a look at the link you've given

Answer (score 0):

This whole thing is flummoxing me. The current methodology I use to encrypt the crypt field is based on a single includes file - Form PHP Kit Includes File originally written by Nick Selby and updated by Simon Wolfe

The stuff on Sagepay's website is endless - loads of files.

Is there a simple update to the original single file??

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30842023/sagepay-2-22-to-3-00-form-upgrade-php-update-to-aes-encryption